# How to see how much prossesing time a C# Windows Forms application needs?

Tags: c#, winforms, timing

I have a C# Windows Forms application wicht does some camera control and computer vision. For all the parts which take longer for calculation I used seperate threads. But there are still some parts which are in the callback functions of the GUI. As I understand, all these callback functions are executed in the same thread. Is there a way to see how much time this thread is working or idle? What percentage of idle time is needed such that the GUI is still responsive?

Comment: you can use this idea mentioned in the following question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954571/how-to-calculate-execution-time-of-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 2):

It's [recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/20/keeping-apps-fast-and-fluid-with-asynchrony-in-the-windows-runtime.aspx) that you shouldn't block the UI thread for more than 50ms, otherwise it will affect the UI responsiveness. I.e., two UI callbacks queued with `Form.BeginInvoke`, each taking ~50ms to complete, may introduce some unpleasant UI experience to the user.

It doesn't make sense to update the UI more often than the user can react to it (i.e, ~24 frames per second). So, you should throttle the UI thread callbacks and give user input events a priority.

I recently posted an example of how it can possibly be done:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21654436/1768303

Answer (score 0):

For simple tasks you could use a stopwatch and measure the time manually. However I think you'll need to check what a [performance profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) is.

Also - there is little situations in which your GUI needs that heavy processing. In most cases the problem comes from putting too much calculations in event handlers instead of implementing them somewhere outside and then update the form when finished. It's less of a single/multi-threading problem and more of using available events properly.